# Apollo Server and MySQL: How to get data direct from the database?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, graphql, apollo-server

currently I'm writing a GraphQL API with ApolloServer/NodeJS. I have a MySQL Database. Because I'm new at this topic, I dont have any idea how can I get data directly from my database. My api sends article information to the client (this is the only purpose of my api). The client can search a specific article via ID (every article/products has a specific ID in the database. The id which the client is typing in should be compared with the id in the database. So if the id = 1 then the api should look after the article which has the id = 1 in the DATABASE and sends the requested information about THIS article to the client. (I know that this might be better with PHP, but I have some trouble with PHP). But I don't know how I can write this into my resolver.

Here is my resolver:

```
const models = require('../models');

module.exports = {
    Query: {
        article: (parent, {id}) => {
                return models.articledata.find(
                    (c) => c.id == id
                );
        }
    },

    Node: {
        __resolveType(node) {
            if(node.toObject().name){
                return 'Article';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my models:

```
let articledata = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'title',
    description: 'Beispiel',
    imgs: 'www.test.de/img',
    btnLink: 'shoplink',
    headline: 'Spicy das neue Spiel',
    introduction: 'Beispiel',
    definition: 'Beispiel',
    tutorial: 'Beispiel',
    specsText: 'Beispiel',
    endText: 'Beispiel',
    age: 12,
    duration: 30,
    players: 12,
    category: 'Beispiel',
    designer: 'Beispiel',
    language: 'Deutsch',
    releaseDate: 2020,
    topic: 'Beispiel',
}];

module.exports = { articledata };
```

And here is my index.js:

```
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server');

const schema = require('./schema');
const resolvers = require('./resolvers');

const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs: schema,
    resolvers,
    dataSources: () => {
        articleAPI: new ArticleAPI()
    }
})

//The listen-method launches a web server
server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
    console.log('Server ready at ${url}');
});
```

Of course I searched on the web, but nothing seems to work for me. I'm very glad about your help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you check out the Apollo Server documentation? There is a lot of good information of connecting data sources to your server [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/tutorial/data-source/).

There's a section about SQL connections [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/tutorial/data-source/#connect-a-database). The documentation notes that Apollo does not provide dedicated SQL connections right now, but shows you how to create one by working through an example.

Comment: I already read this, but it just works with data, which is written directly in the code. But my complete data is in my mysql database. Is it maybe possible to replace the data in the models with variables. The variables then come from a php-file that gives me data and I implement them in the models?